# Dynamic creation of screens based on data configured in DB tables

Tags: asp.net

I am developing the application in Visual Studio 2010 with C# and asp.net
In my application user can configure the Number of tabs(left menu) that he want to see.
User can created fields & he can associate each filed to a tab & the index(position which states is it a first field in the tab or second etc) of the field in that tab.

I am saving tab details in one table & field details in another table.
When user logs in he has to get the number of tabs & in each tab number of fields & then display the tabs. And when a particular Tab is clicked, the fields associated with that tab should be shown on the screen.

On the bottom of screen there should be a Save button. On click of this button data entered in each field should be saved.

Please help me how to create the dynamic screen

Comment: Which language, what's the context? Java, Python, Cocoa,..., desktop, web, mobile,...? There is no information that enables us to help you. Not even the tag providing any information. You described your problem in a generic way, you cannot get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a collection of tabs or fields read from DB than you can just use a Repeater control and bind it to the data from the database.